# Render html instead of JSON from JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm using the jQuery FullCalendar plugin with Ruby on Rails, and now I want to show the event details in a jquery dialog when you click on an event in the calendar.
I have this in my controller EventsController

```
  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.xml
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @event }
      format.js { render :json => @event.to_json }
    end
  end
```

which works as intended if I visit the url /events/1 for example. Then I see the form generated in app/views/events/show.html.erb. 
However, in my calendar.js where I'm trying to GET that form and insert it into my dialog div with this code:

```
    // http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/
    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){
      $.get('/events/' + event.id, function(data, text, jqXhr) {
          eventdialog.html(data);
          eventdialog.dialog("open");
      });
    },
```

'data' only contains the JSON-data. 
Sorry if this is a nooby question, but i've tried googling for hours now but I can't seem to find what i'm looking for.
Using RoR 3.2.2.

Comment: There are a good few links available on Google. http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/get-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line should be like format.js { render :partial => 'event' }

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it didn't work though. I got this error from the server:

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial events/event, application/event with {:handlers=>[:erb, :coffee, :builder], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/cakism/railscode/calendar/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:29:in `show'
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:26:in `show'

Comment: This is a example. Error says you should implement '_event.html.erb' file. I thought you already have this file. Try {render :template => 'show'} or {render :template => 'show', :layout => false} in this case, only html from 'show.html.erb' will be sent.